# Add labels to levelplot

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

I am producing a levelplot from a matrix. I have another matrix, of the same dimensions of the first one, with labels. I would like to add the labels to the plot -the square plotting a color for the value should also show the label. Is there a way to do that? Thanks in advance.

As an example, here is the following code. I would like each label in matrix *source* to be shown on top of the part of the graph corresponding to the same data in matrix *value* with the same coordinates.

```
library(lattice)

value <- matrix(data=2^seq(from=0.5,to=2,length.out=9),ncol=3,nrow=3)

colnames(value)<-c("wheat","barley","rice")

rownames(value)<-c("1970","1980","1990")

source <- matrix(data=c("A","A","B","A","B","C","C","B","C"),ncol=3,nrow=3)

levelplot(value,xlab="year",ylab="comodity",main="some plot")
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and what you mean by "add the labels". Do you mean labels of `contourplot`? Something else?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possibility:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

dat <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = c(1970, 1980, 1990), y = c("wheat","barley","rice")), 
              value = 2^seq(from=0.5,to=2,length.out=9), source = c("A","A","B","A","B","C","C","B","C"))

Obj <- 
  levelplot(value ~ x+y, data = dat, xlab = "year", ylab = "comodity", main = "some plot") + 
  xyplot(y ~ x, data = dat,
   panel = function(y, x, ...) {
           ltext(x = x, y = y, labels = dat$source, cex = 1, font = 2,
           fontfamily = "HersheySans")
   })

print(Obj)
```

[image]